# How can a four way set associative cache mapping be made to approximate hit time of direct mapping?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

It is well-known in cache design that direct mapping has the smallest hit time whereas a 4-way set-associative mapping has a higher hit rate than its direct mapping counterpart. How can 4-way set-associative mapping be made to approximate the hit time of direct mapping?
(here, adequate information about extra hardware involved has to be given)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not sure about the statement "It is well-known in cache design that direct mapping has the smallest hit time".

Anyway, if you want a 4 way associative cache to have the same hit time as a direct mapped cache, you need former's TAG comparison logic to be as fast as the latter. In a associative cache, once you've​ located the block, you need to do a walk (sequential comparison of entries) to identify if its a hit or miss. However if you have 4 comparators (4 way associative) you could do the comparison in parallel, hence no need to walk.

Having said that, its hard to believe modern caches lacks this feature, hence my note at the beginning.